# Read file and find if all lines are the same length

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, file, operating-system

Using python I need to read a file and determine if all lines are the same length or not. If they are I move the file into a "good" folder and if they aren't all the same length I move them into a "bad" folder and write a word doc that says which line was not the same as the rest. Any help or ways to start?

Comment: Could you provide a snippet of code please? Hint: It will take several 'for' loops and do-while loops to get this task done, plus storing the status of each line and each page. Plus VBS for the Word doc, which is created as a template that is called each time it is needed to produce output. A lot of work here.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `all()`:

```
with open(filename) as read_file:
    length = len(read_file.readline())
    if all(len(line) == length for line in read_file):
        # Move to good folder
    else:
        # Move to bad folder
```

Since `all()` is short-circuiting, it will stop reading the file at the first non-match.

Comment: I am trying to us this method and i keep getting this error                       length = len(file.readline())
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'readline'

Comment: @JustinStarkman: Sorry, I had a slight typo.  It's fixed now.

Answer (score -1):

First off, you can read the file, here `example.txt` and put all lines in a list, `content`:

```
with open(filename) as f:
   content = f.readlines()
```

Next you need to trim all the newline characters from the end of a line and put it in another list `result`:

```
for line in content:
   line = line.strip()
   result.append(line)
```

Now it's not that hard to get the length of every sentence, and since you want lines that are bad, you loop through the list:

```
for line in result:
    lengths.append(len(line))
```

So the i-th element of `result` has length [i-th element of `lengths`]. We can make a counter for what line length occurs the most in the list, it is as simple as one line!

```
most_occuring = max(set(lengths), key=lengths.count)
```

Now we can make another `for-loop` to check which lengths don't correspond with the most-occuring and add those to `bad-lines`:

```
for i in range(len(lengths)):
    if (lengths[i] != most_occuring):
        bad_lines.append([i, result[i]])
```

The next step is check where the file needs to go, the good folder, or the bad folder:

```
if len(bad_lines == 0):
    #Good file, move it to the good folder, use the os or shutil module
    os.rename("path/to/current/file.foo", "path/to/new/desination/for/file.foo")
else:
   #Bad file, one or more lines are bad, thus move it to the bad folder
   os.rename("path/to/current/file.foo", "path/to/new/desination/for/file.foo")
```

The last step is writing the bad lines to another file, which is do-able, since we have the bad lines already in a list `bad_lines`:

```
with open("bad_lines.txt", "wb") as f:
    for bad_line in bad_lines:
        f.write("[%3i]  %s\n" % (bad_line[0], bad_line[1]))
```

It's not a doc file, but I think this is a nice start. You can take a look at the docx module if you really want to write to a doc file.

EDIT: Here is an example python script.

```
with open("example.txt") as f:
    content = f.readlines()

result = []
lengths = []

#Strip the file of \n
for line in content:
    line = line.strip()
    result.append(line)
    lengths.append(len(line))

most_occuring = max(set(lengths), key=lengths.count)
bad_lines = []

for i in range(len(lengths)):
    if (lengths[i] != most_occuring):
        #Append the bad_line to bad_lines
        bad_lines.append([i, result[i]])

#Check if it's a good, or a bad file
#if len(bad_lines == 0):
    #Good File
    #Move file to the good folder...
#else:
    #Bad File

with open("bad_lines.txt", "wb") as f:
    for bad_line in bad_lines:
        f.write("[%3i]  %s\n" % (bad_line[0], bad_line[1]))
```

Comment: `line = line.strip()` will trim a bit more than just the newline character at the end of a line.

Comment: There is no need to strip the newlines anyway.  They should be the same length.

Comment: You are right about it stripping a bit more, but it gets the job done. You could also indeed remove it, but it looks neater in the list. If you leave it out, you should also remove the \n in the write-file part. 
Is this the reason by the way that this got downvoted? This is my first answer so I'd like to know what to improve.
I can't comment on your answer zondo, but he also asks for the lines which are different, so you have to loop through all of them. Take note that in my answer also parts could be put together in one loop for better time efficiency (not much, it will still be O(n))

Comment: Thank you for the awesome response! One question, where did you define result? Im getting a NameError: for result.append(line)

Comment: NameError: global name 'result' is not defined

Comment: I didn't include the full code, but you indeed need to declare the variables, I edited the answer and added the full code.